# Primeng table: add rows to table in ngOnInit

Tags: primeng

I'm using the following code, taken from Primeng:

[Table](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/basic)

It displays only the header of the table.

I want to add few rows with static values in the ts code.

Can you please provide sample code ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

Following is the way to add static values to table.

```js
export class TableBasicDemo implements OnInit {

    cars: Car[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
    }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="first">Basic</h3>
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Vin</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
        <tr>
            <td>{{car.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{car.year}}</td>
            <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{car.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant:

```js
    cars: Car[];

    this.cars = [
          { vin: 0, year:0, brand:0, color:0 },
          { vin: 0, year:0, brand:0, color:0 },
...
          { vin: 0, year:0, brand:0, color:0 },

      ];

export interface Car{
  vin;
  brand;
  color;
}
```